# How to create a file in a python package based on module path?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a project laid out like this:

```
-proj/
    -__init__.py
    -main/
        -__init__.py
        -written_files/
            -__init__.py
    -scripts/
        -create_file.py
```

In `create_file.py`, I want to create a file, `train.txt`, and put it in `proj/main/written_files/`

I was wondering if I could use the relative package structure. I was thinking of putting something like this in `create_file.py`:

```
train_file = open(proj.main.written_files.train.txt, 'w')
```

Is there some way to do something like this?

Comment: From `proj.main.written_files.train.txt` you should already guess that that such a syntax is not possible because it is ambiguous. What if the file was called `file.some.more.dots.txt`? Your approach would assume that the file was somewhere inside a deeply nested directory structure.

Comment: In general, I would recommend to use absolute paths when opening files, because otherwise it depends on from which directory you run the script. Something like `with open(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/file.txt', 'w') as file:` should work, if `file.txt` is in the same directory like the file in which this code is. I guess you should be able to use this code snippet if you adapt it to your directory structure.

Comment: @MichaelH. Relative paths are fine as long as you're careful, but you're right in general, since the current directory can change between generating a relative file name and using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules loaded from a file will generally have a [`__file__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__file__) attribute. You can use this as a starting point for getting around your package. You could use the utilties in [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) or [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to navigate around the path. Either of the following should work:

```
from os.path import dirname, join

filename = join(dirname(dirname(__file__)), 'main', 'written_files', 'train.txt')
```

OR

```
from pathlib import Path

filename = Path(__file__).parent.parent / 'main' / 'written_files' / 'train.txt'
```

In both cases, use a context manager to make sure your file gets closed no matter what:

```
with open(filename, 'w') as train_file:
    ...
```

Neither of these solutions is super elegant because they involve walking up the directory tree. Instead, you could start with the project root, and walk down:

```
filename = join(dirname(proj.__file__), 'main', 'written_files', 'train.txt')
```

OR

```
filename = Path(proj.__file__).parent / 'main' / 'written_files' / 'train.txt'
```

In both cases, `proj.__file__` should point to the root level `__init__.py`.